# How to databind properties exposed from an ObservableCollection when the ObservableCollection is exposed from a view model?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm unable to find the correct binding syntax to data bind properties on items contained in an ObservableCollection when said ObservableCollection is exposed from a view model.

When I data bind the model's observable collection directly, it works. When I data bind the model's observable collection as exposed by the view model, it doesn't. This is a XAML/C# Windows Store 8.1 app.

**What I currently get out of my skeleton test**

```
{binding Path=ID}
{binding Path=Letter}
```

**What I want**

```
1
a
```

## Here's my skeleton test

**I have an Item class**

Items are stored in the observable collection and I will ultimately want to bind against the ID and Letter properties:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int id, char letter)
    {
        ID = id;
        Letter = letter;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public char Letter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**The Model class** contains an observable collection of items

```
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _theItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _theItems = value;
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Item> _theItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
}
```

I have a **ViewModel** that exposes the Model's observable collection

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(Model model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> theItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _model.Items;
        }
    }

    private Model _model;
}
```

My **MainPage** constructor creates the model with some test data, creates the ViewModel, and sets the page's DataContext to the view model:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Model model = new Model();

    // some test data
    model.Items.Add(new Item(1, 'a'));

    _viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

My **MainPage XAML** looks like this

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=theItems}" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>{binding Path=ID}</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>{binding Path=Letter}</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

This test skeleton is intended to simplify yet mimic my real goal which is to have a view model that exposes several things, one of which is an observable collection of objects whose different properties I want to bind. But binding the properties on items exposes from the observable collection eludes me.

I assume my problem relates to the XAML binding syntax. I am thinking that because I set the page's DataContext to the ViewModel, that setting the ItemsSource of the GridView to theItems would then allow me to refer to the ID and Letter properties of the items inside the collection.

When I directly bind the model's ObservableCollection to the MainPage's DataContext, all is well. But that departs from my goal with the ViewModel which is to expose additional things besides the ObservableCollection that I want to bind to from a singular view model.

I've tried various blog posts and things mentioned here on StackOverflow to no avail. Help appreciated.

Comment: The catch in the end is to provide the **Text=** part.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your **XAML** bindings.

```
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ID, Mode=OneTime}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Letter, Mode=OneTime}"/>
...
```

Consider to change the `DataTemplate`.

```
...
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <Run Text="{Binding ID,Mode=OneTime}"/>
            <Run Text=" - "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Letter,Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
...
```